# webview javascript event notification

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, uiwebview, webview

In my cocoa application, I have a small web view. It runs some javascript, is there a way I can be notified when a button is pressed for example? or some javascript function is triggered?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about UIWebViews (as you have indicated with your tags): No, there is no direct way to call Objective-C code from inside a UIWebView.

You can however use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` and poll for changes. Example: if you want to get notified when a certain global JS variable changes, you can use

```
NSString *variableContent = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myGlobalVariable"];
```

Call this code from a repeating timer, store the retrieved content and perform your action whenever the content changes.